# Etimología de "pinatar"

Tags: etimología, sufijos, nombres-colectivos

[**San Pedro del Pinatar**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Pedro_del_Pinatar#Toponimia_y_gentilicio) es una localidad que debe su nombre, en parte, a que antiguamente era *«una extensa masa forestal donde abundaban los pinos»*, llamada simplemente **El Pinatar**. Se entiende entonces que ***pinatar*** tendrá un significado parecido a **pinar**.

Y efectivamente, aunque hoy en día ya no aparece ***pinatar*** en el diccionario, si buscamos en el [NTLLE](http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) podemos comprobar que sí estaba contemplada con ese significado entre 1925 y 1989, en diferentes ediciones y versiones del Diccionario de la Academia:

[image]

Sin embargo, no termino de ver clara la etimología de la palabra, y ninguna de las entradas del NTLLE la incluye.

El uso del sufijo ***-ar*** para formar sustantivos colectivos referidos a árboles y plantas, es bien conocido: *pino → pinar, limón → limonar, castaño → castañar, olivo → olivar, rosal → rosalar* (este último no está recogido tampoco en el DLE pero se encuentra en topónimos de mi zona).
Sin embargo, en este caso el sufijo parece ser ***-atar***: *pino → pinatar*. Y no conozco ningún caso de uso de este sufijo para formar este tipo de sustantivos, ni me ha parecido ver ninguno tampoco al [buscar en el DLE palabras terminadas en *-atar*](https://dle.rae.es/?w=atar&m=32) (la más parecida, [patatar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=S87XLtx), viene en realidad de *patata + -ar*, así que no vale).

Entonces, ¿de dónde viene ***pinatar***? ¿Cómo se formó? ¿Hay otros ejemplos similares de uso de este supuesto sufijo *-atar*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viene de *pinato*, palabra típica de la región de Murcia, donde se encuentra la localidad de San Pedro del Pinatar:

> **[pinato](https://dle.rae.es/?id=T2AknFp)**
>
> 1. m. *Mur.* Pino tierno y de poca altura, cuyas ramas tocan el suelo.

Luego en *pinatar* simplemente se ha añadido el sufijo *[-ar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3NNxyGS)* que mencionas en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

La palabra *pinato* como de uso en la región de Murcia aparece recogida por primera vez en el Pagés de 1925, con la misma definición que la actual del DLE. Esta fue adoptada por el *Academia Manual* de la RAE de 1927, y añadida al *Academia Usual* en 1936. Aunque no aparece su etimología explícita, entiendo que *pinato* se forma con el sufijo *[-ato](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4GZKKGk)*, usado para designar a las crías de algunos animales, como *cervato* o *ballenato*.

Por último, rebuscando en el fichero de la RAE veo que la voz *pinato* aparece recogida en el *Vocabulario murciano* de Alberto Sevilla, de 1919.

Comment: @walen digo típica porque lo dice el diccionario, lo que no sé es si será frecuente...